# Why is Morph not considered an ability?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Reading FAQs concerning [Muraganda Petroglyphs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muraganda%20Petroglyphs) and morph cards, a face down morph creature will get the `+2/+2` bonus from [Muraganda Petroglyphs](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Muraganda%20Petroglyphs).

What I don't understand is why. Since the face down creature gets `+2/+2` form the glyphs, that implies the creature has no abilities. Yet the creature can be turned face up by its morph cost. If that is not an ability, what is it exactly?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The face down morph cards don't have an ability whose effect turns the card face-up. Instead, the rules allow you to turn them face-up.

> 702.36d If you have priority, you may turn a face-down permanent you control face up. This is a special action; it doesn’t use the stack (see rule 115). To do this, show all players what the permanent’s morph cost would be if it were face up, pay that cost, then turn the permanent face up. (If the permanent wouldn’t have a morph cost if it were face up, it can’t be turned face up this way.) The morph effect on it ends, and it regains its normal characteristics. Any abilities relating to the permanent entering the battlefield don’t trigger when it’s turned face up and don’t have any effect, because the permanent has already entered the battlefield.

Comment: Playing a land is another example of a special action enabled by the rules. There are six in total, listed in CR 115.

Comment: This is the same reason why you can use Morph to respond to a spell with Split Second: SS prevents activating abilities and casting spells, but Morph is a special action (often accompanied by a triggered ability, which is also not stopped by SS, which in turn lets you do things like counter, redirect, or copy the SS spell using the appropriate morph creatures).

Comment: Possibly worth considering for inclusion in this answer: ***707.2.** Face-down spells and face-down permanents have no characteristics other than those listed by the ability or rules that allowed the spell or permanent to be face down.*

Comment: @Rainbolt, That's the basis's of the OP's question. He asked how can Morph work if this is so. Doesn't make sense to include it in the answer.

Comment: I found a more appropriate avenue for [my concerns](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/19211/6692).